# Checking input type...how?

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
public void addStudent(){

    String fName, lName;
    double mGrade, fGrade;
    System.out.print("\nEnter first name: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    fName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nEnter last name: ");
    lName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nEnter midterm grade: ");
    mGrade = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nEnter final grade: ");
    fGrade = in.nextDouble();
    Student toAdd = new Student(fName, lName, mGrade, fGrade);
    students.add(toAdd);
    System.out.println("\nStudent record added.\n");
    System.out.println(students.size());
}
```

How can I check if the user typed in something other than an integer for midterm grade and final grade? And if they entered a non-integer,  I want the method to just request the user type in that value again. I'm guessing I'll have to use a do-while loop. But I don't don't know how to check the type...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to check to see if a String represents an integer in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java)

Comment: @mike - thanks, that might help. i'm not allowed to add methods for this problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a do-while will work best.

```
  int midterm;
  System.out.printLn("Enter midterm grade");
  do
  { 
      try {
          string s = in.nextLine();
          midterm = Integer.parseInt(s);
          break;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          System.out.printLn("Couldn't parse input, please try again");
      }
  }
  while (true);
```

Comment: er, i messed up in my description...can i parse a double?

Comment: Absolutely, instead of integer, use Double.parse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Scanner.next()` and try to parse it to the type you want (ex. to integer by using `Integer.parseInt(x)` and if it fails (throws and exception) try to do it again.

Comment: er, i messed up in my original post. can i parse a double?

Comment: Yes you can, you can do that by using `Double.parseDouble(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You may use the method: nextInt() from Scanner

Alternatively you can check if a string is an integer like this:

```
if( someString.matches("\\d+") ) {
  // it is 
} else {
 // it isn't 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully for a similar issue I was having.  I much prefer this to making a try/catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Run the input method in a loop, if user enters something other than valid integer or double, repeat asking for the input.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String input;
        int ch1;
        float ch2;
        String ch3;

        Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);

        input = one.nextLine();

        try {
            ch1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println("integer");
            return;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {


        }

        try {
            ch2 = Float.parseFloat(input);
            System.out.println("float");
            return;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
        try {
            ch3 = String.valueOf(input);
            System.out.println("String");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }


    }
}
```