# Data type recognition

Tags: java, types

I want to create a Java program where
 a user will input something and the output will show what type of data the input is..?
For example:

```
Input: 25
Output: integer
Input: ABC
Output: string
Input: 12.7
Output: float/double.
```

Please help as I am clueless on how to work this out

Comment: Look for parsing data from string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking input type...how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333110/checking-input-type-how)

Comment: [This previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40062753/2449857) shows exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your purpose:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataType 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      if(in.hasNextByte(2))
         System.out.println("Byte");
      else if(in.hasNextInt())
         System.out.println("Integer");
      else if(in.hasNextFloat())
         System.out.println("Float");
      else if(in.hasNextBoolean())
         System.out.println("Boolean");
      else if(in.hasNext())
         System.out.println("String");
   }
}
```

Note that the order of `if...else` statements is very important here because of the following set relations with respect to patterns:

1. All byte patterns can be integers
2. All integer patterns can be floats
3. All float patterns can be Strings
4. All booleans can be Strings

There are quite a lot of `hasNext..()` methods in the `Scanner` class, such as `BigInteger`, `short`, and so on. You may refer the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class documentation for further details.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach could go like this; starting with some input **string** X.

1. If X can be parsed as Integer --> it is an int/Integer
2. Then you try Long
3. Then Float
4. Then Double
5. If nothing worked, you probably have a string there

( with "parsing" I mean using methods such as [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) ... you pass in X; and when that method doesn't throw an exception on you, you know that X is an Integer/int )

But: such a *detection* very much depends on your definition of valid inputs; and potential mappings. As there zillions of ways of interpreting a string. It might not be a number; but given a correct format string ... it could be timestamp.

So the very first step: clarify your requirements! Understand the potential input formats you have to support; then think about their "mapping"; and a potential check to identify that type.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a string and try to parse it as other types:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);//allows user input
input = s.nextLine();//reads user input
try{//java will try to execute the code but will go to the catch block if there's an exception.
    int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input);//try to convert input to int
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();//this tell you exactly what went wrong. If you get here, then the input isn't an integer.
}
//same with double
```

Comment: Now a hint for you: never ever suggest to a newbie to go with an **empty** catch block. That is super-bad practice!

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, I was thinking how exactly to explain what **should** go there