# How to check whether a particular index in ArrayList has characters in the range of A to Z

Tags: android

Android 2.3.3

I have an ArrayList which has both Numbers(in string format) and also words like (and, plus, by, ...)

I wish to retrieve numbers only from this ArrayList.

I can get the value using get(index) and convert to number, if it a number that can be converted. If i use a loop to iterate, conversion of words will throw me an exception. So, how do i check, without getting an exception.

Will this work:::

I use a try catch block and when there is an exception, I just write "continue;" in the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to convert in a `try` block, and ignore the exception in the `catch` block. (Just `continue` the loop, like you suggested). It will work.

Another method, without making use of exceptions handling;

[Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)

[How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java)

And there are many more.