# I am trying to set a requirement to only enter an integer and if anything else ins entered show error message

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

```
        ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"There are currently "+clubSize+" people inside right now" +
                                                            "\nHow many People are in your party today.");
        int partyIn;
        try
            {
           partyIn = Integer.parseInt(ans);
            }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "What you entered was not a number: " + ans);
            }
        if (clubSize + partyIn <= 125)
            {
            clubSize = clubSize + partyIn; 
            peopleIn = peopleIn + partyIn;
            }
        else
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry you have to many people in your party");
            }
```

this is coming back with a error: variable partyIn might not have been initialized

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that `Integer.parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the inputted number isn't a real number.  Catch that exception and then notify the user of the error.

```
int partyIn;
try
{
   partyIn = Integer.parseInt(ans);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "What you entered was not a number: " + ans);
}
```

Comment: I have never used the try or catch code before so excuse me if this is a dumb question, but I edited my code above and put it the way you had it but it is coming up with an error.

Comment: What we've done here is created a possibility of the `partyIn` variable not being initialized.  Assuming that your code is in a method, try a `return` statement inside the `catch` block, so that if the code gets past the catch block, then the compiler knows that `parseInt` succeeded, and that `partyIn` has been initialized.

Comment: adding in the return statement allows it to compile and sends the error message, but it just ends the program, do i just add in a loop to get it to ask the question again?

Comment: Actually to get it to work I added in a while(true) loop and added a break in the catch instead of a return and this seemed to work. Thank you for your help though.