# Comma separators in a string of digits

Tags: java, arrays, separator

There is a string `data`:

```
{4,15,26,7}
```

Comma separator is used to separate digits.

```
this.points=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            this.points.add(Character.getNumericValue(data.charAt(i)));
    }
```

How to modify this code to be able to skip comma separators and save only digits in `this.points`?

Comment: this.points.add(Character.getNumericValue(data.charAt(i+1))); try this

Comment: Alwyas data in this format {4,15,26,7}

Comment: Wouldn't you then lose the important distinction between "4,15" and "41,5"? Are you really happy to lose that data?

Comment: Do you want digits or numbers? You can split the string by commas and then save the digits/numbers one at a time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: This is the case. If "4,15", then I need to save 4 and 15. If "41,5", then - 41 and 5. Comma separator should be used to extract integers.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: Right, so you *don't* want to skip commas and save just the digits as you described. You want to *split* on commas and save the *numbers*. Big difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
String data="{4,15,26,7}";
data=data.substring(1,data.length-1);
String[] digits=data.split(",");
his.points=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            this.points.add(Integer.parseInt(digits[i]));
    }
```

Comment: Given the comments, I suggest you change your code to use Integer.parseInt. At the moment it won't actually compile, as you're trying to add a String to an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that hard. Here are my sources:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2011/09/string-split-example-in-java-tutorial.html

[Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)

So what you would want to do is this:

```
points = new ArrayList<Integer>;
String foo = "4,15,10,100";
String[] splits = foo.split(",");

for(String temp : splits){
if(Character.digit(temp)) points.add(Integer.parseInt(temp);
}
```