# How to check if the input is an integer?

Tags: java

I am taking input as integer using Scanner class. like this:`in.nextInt();`
I need to prompt "wrong input" if user has entered any floating point number or character or string. 
How can i accomplish this ?

Comment: have you looked into `try-catch` statements?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `Scanner.nextInt()`:  http://doc.java.sun.com/DocWeb/api/java.util.Scanner?

Comment: no, how can i use it to make it work ?

Comment: @roliu `Scanner#nextInt()` is probably the least advisable thing you could do to receive user input due to the lack of robustness. For example, if the user enters something that cannot be parsed into an integer, the program will crash.

Comment: @JoshM I don't know what the most popular standard is for reading input from a user in java, but you can clearly prevent `nextInt()` from crashing your program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking to see if a string is an integer - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048604/checking-to-see-if-a-string-is-an-integer-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

[`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) can only return an `int` if the `InputStream` contains an `int` as the next readable token.

If you want to validate input, you should use something like `nextLine()` to read a full `String`, and use [`Integer.parseInt(thatString)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to check if it is an integer.

The method will throw a

> **NumberFormatException** - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a try-catch body.

```
String input = scanner.next();
int inputInt  0;
try
{
   inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
} catch (Exception e)
{
   System.out.println("Wrong input");
   System.exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, try using the `try-catch` statement

```
int someInteger;

try {
    someInteger = Scanner.nextInt();    
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("The value you have input is not a valid integer");
}
```