# how to check whether the input is integer or not

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I a making  a program that will ask an int input from user and check whether user input is an integer or not. If no the program asks for an input tile it gets a integer.

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Eneter a nuber here:");
    int num;
    if (in.hasNextInt()){
        num =in.nextInt();
        if(num % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print("this is even!!");
        } else{
            System.out.println("this is odd!!");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.print("pleas enter an integer only!!!");
        num = in.nextInt();
        if(num % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print("this is even second check!!");
        } else{
            System.out.println("this is odd second check!!");
        }
    }
```

here is the code but i have some mistakes in there. it brings an error when input is not an int. pleas help with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678939/how-to-check-if-the-input-is-an-integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, it will end only if its a valid Integer otherwise it will keep asking for Integer and I think you are looking for the same.

```
public void checkInt() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Eneter a nuber here:");
    try {
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print("this is even!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("this is odd!!");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("pleas enter an integer only!!!");
        checkInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be a stupid way but this can solve your problem:

```
        String x;
        x = "5";//or get it from user
        int y;
        try{
        y = Integer.parseInt(x);
        System.out.println("INTEGER");
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.println("NOT INTEGER");
        }
```

**Edited:**

The program will try to convert the string to integer. If it is integer it will succeed else it will get exception and be caught.

Another way is to check the **ASCII** value.

To continue till integer is encountered:

```
String x;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean notOk;
        do{
            x = sc.next();
            notOk = check(x);
        }while(notOk);
        System.out.println("Integer found");
    }
    private static boolean check(String x){
        int y;
        try{
            y = Integer.parseInt(x);
            return false;
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: yeah thank you pretty helpful but how can i get that infinite loop in catch part to get in integer from for an input???

Answer (score 1):

You must read user input as String. Then, inside a try/catch block, make a casting to integer (Integer.parseInt()), if throws a exception is because is not a number.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Test {
     public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

     if(sc.hasNextInt())
         System.out.println("Input is of int type");

     else
         System.out.println("This is something else");
     }
}
```

Comment: OP faced error because of some other reason. He already has used this code in his/her answer! A -1.