# Inifnite loop while reading numbers

Tags: java

Basically I am trying to write a program that will read a finite set of values from the user then print the average. (I know how to do the calculations so I will leave those out.)

I am having a problem with the logic side of the loop.

I understand that everyone here would prefer that I attempted it but I am new to loops and I am having extreme difficulties understanding loop logic.

I am attempting to do this assignment for my class but the teacher is flying through material and does not help at all when questions are asked. When I ask for help with a problem he says do your best to attempt it and I will grade it accordingly?

I honestly do not know where to start.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4Point5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Status = "";
    int count = 0;

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        count++;
}        

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
//Do calculations here?
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When I was trying other ways to get the values from the user it made an infinite loop.

Comment: I think it will read allways an number from keuboard, but never reach the for loop.

Comment: My problem is not reading the numbers. I just do not know how to end the loop so that it can use the numbers to perform the calculations in either another loop or just a method to calculate the average, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never get the next element:

```
while (in.hasNext()) 
    count++;
```

You are always on the 1<sup>st</sup> element and asking if there is a 2<sup>nd</sup> element.

You should use:

```
while (in.hasNext()) 
  int next = sc.nextInt();
```

BTW: please avoid statement without curly brackets. It is the root of all evil.

Comment: I realized the brackets after. I know it is not good practice to leave them out. 

The line
    Integer next = sc.nextInt(); 

This will read only a single number and set it to next, right?

Comment: @NewToJava Read the documentation and you'll better understand what it does.

Comment: @NewToJava Yes, as indicated in the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt() `Scans the next token of the input as an int.`

Comment: But how would I make it exit the loop?

It is constantly accepting values but what would I do to make it use the values?

Comment: @NewToJava You have to decide how to detect the end of the loop. There are usually 3 solutions : **either** you decide that `-1` means `stop` **or** you first ask the user howmany numbers to add, **or** at each step, you ask the user if he/she wants to add another number.

Answer (score 3):

When you read for the first time, you don't read anymore, so [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) will stay always `true` since there will always be *next* element, which is.. the current element you're reading.

One solution is to do something like that:

```
String input = null;
while((input = in.next()) != null) {
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
while (in.nextInt() != 'SOME INT TO STOP LOOP') 
        count++;
```

Instead of verify every time if we have an entered number, we can verify if the entered number is an stop condition.

Comment: If it is supposed to take any value, wouldn't making an int to stop the loop force a certain integer to not be allowed?

Comment: Good question. You can use an negative number, or, better, instead of, you can use `next()` and convert de given string, if its a number you count, if not, you exit the loop.

Comment: See here[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java], good examples of verify if is a integer.