# Generate Variables from array to create loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I have this array which I am generating when reading and splitting variables from a text file. I then Need to parse split variable in the array into an integer and surround it in a try catch in case the data is not an integer. I am trying to avoid creating a try catch block for each variable in the array. This is my code so far:

```
String [] tempList = data.split("-");

String [] variables = {"readerNo", "seconds", "minutes", "hours", 
                       "days", "month", "year", "other","empNo"};
int readerNo, seconds, minutes, hours, days, month, year,other, empNo;
/*
* parsing of data to integers/boolean
*/

//-----------
for(int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
    try{
        *variable name should be here* = Integer.parseInt(tempList[i]); 
    }catch(Exception E){
        *variable name should be here* = -1; 
    }
}
```

Would it be possible or would I need to create a try catch block for each?

Comment: Check this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java

Comment: It is bad practice to catch Exception, catch NumberFormatException instead.

Comment: You are right @Raphaël. Bad habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it like that:

```
int[] myNumbers = new int[tempList.length];
for(int i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++){
  try{
     myNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempList[i]); 
  }catch(Exception E){
     myNumbers[i] = -1; 
  }
}
```

Thats the method to avoid the try{}- Blocks :)

Comment: He wrote that he wants to avoid writing try-catch for every single variable :)

Comment: it is different because he, for every single variable, uses an own integer. I just use a integer[]

Comment: I think that he wants to have it answered like I did because he has like 8 integers.

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice way is to use a regex:

```
if(tempList[i].matches("-?\\d+"))
{
  Integer.parseInt(tempList[i]); 
}
```

There are several ways to check if a string represents an integer. If you want to dodge that exception you will need to know it is an int before attempting a parse. See here for related: [Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)