# String to Integer from TextField

Tags: java, string, integer, libgdx

Stuck on attempting to convert a String to an Integer. I'm using libgdx & I've tried a few mothods of doing it & I keep getting null in return.

Here is my most recent method I've tried also the easiest.

```
String x = textfield_1.getText();
String y = textfield_2.getText();
Integer integerfield_1 = Integer.getInteger(textfield_1.getText(), null);
if (integerfield_1 == null) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect Integer (Integer Only)");
} else {
    System.out.println("Please Enter The Position");
    //TODO Fill GUI Form.
}
```

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: I  believe you should use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: reference.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the JavaDocs for [`Integer.getInteger(String, Integer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Integer)) for a sec

> Returns: 
> the Integer value of the property.

Or in longer terms...

> Returns the integer value of the system property with the specified
>   name. The first argument is treated as the name of a system property.
>   System properties are accessible through the
>   System.getProperty(java.lang.String) method. The string value of this
>   property is then interpreted as an integer value, as per the
>   Integer.decode method, and an Integer object representing this value
>   is returned.
>
> - If the property value begins with the two ASCII characters 0x or the ASCII character #, not followed by a minus sign, then the rest of
>     it is parsed as a hexadecimal integer exactly as by the method
>     valueOf(java.lang.String, int) with radix 16.
> - If the property value begins with the ASCII character 0 followed by another character, it is parsed as an octal integer exactly as by the
>     method valueOf(java.lang.String, int) with radix 8.
> - Otherwise, the property value is parsed as a decimal integer exactly as by the method valueOf(java.lang.String, int) with radix
>     10.
>
> The second argument is the default value. The default value is
>   returned if there is no property of the specified name, if the
>   property does not have the correct numeric format, or if the specified
>   name is empty or null.

This is not doing what you think it is...

Instead you should be using [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), this will throw a `NumberFormatException` when the value of the `String` can't be converted to a valid integer...

For example...

```
String x = textfield_1.getText();
String y = textfield_2.getText();
try {
    Integer integerfield_1 = Integer.parseInt(textfield_1.getText());
    System.out.println("Please Enter The Position");
    //TODO Fill GUI Form.
} catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Incorrect Integer (Integer Only)");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, then this

```
Integer integerfield_1 = Integer.getInteger(textfield_1.getText(), null);
```

Should be something like [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) this -

```
int integerfield_1 = 0;
try {
  integerfield_1 = (x != null) ? Integer.parseInt(x.trim()) : 0;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you really want to use `Integer` (the wrapper), then you could use [`Integer.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).

```
Integer integerfield_1 = null;
try {
  integerfield_1 = (x != null) ? Integer.valueOf(x.trim()) : null;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```