# How to check is a string or number?

Tags: swift

I have an array `["abc", "94761178","790"]`

I want to iterate each and check is a `String` or an `Int`?

How to check it?

How to convert "123" to integer 123?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Edit Swift 2.2:**

In swift 2.2 use `Int(yourArray[1])`

```
var yourArray = ["abc", "94761178","790"]
var num = Int(yourArray[1])
if num != nil {
 println("Valid Integer")
}
else {
 println("Not Valid Integer")
}
```

It will show you that string is valid integer and `num` contains valid `Int`.You can do your calculation with `num`.

From docs:

> If the string represents an integer that fits into an Int, returns the
>   corresponding  integer.This accepts strings that match the regular
>   expression "[-+]?[0-9]+" only.

Comment: Be warned that this only works up to 2^31 - 1 (signed integer limit on 32-bit arch). I saw this in a project I'm working on related to phone numbers, and phone numbers can easily surpass that limit.

Comment: This code causes a compile error in Swift 2.2.  "toInt() is no longer available: use Int() initializer"

Comment: @Can good point, this tripped me up too. I added an answer that handles numbers of any size, including 10 or 11 digit phone numbers.

Comment: That's kind of funny; I still think of phone numbers as alpha characters. It wasn't *that* long ago that something like 215-LU6-5858 was a perfectly valid way to represent a phone number. :) I still *mostly* treat them as alpha-numerics in databases, however I'm retraining myself to change that with phone number parsers and dialer code. I do continue to giggle when I see USA-only programmers putting zip codes in number fields. #wisdomofage ;)

Answer (score 75):

Here is a small Swift version using String extension :

Swift 3/Swift 4 :

```
extension String  {
    var isNumber: Bool {
        return !isEmpty && rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
    }
}
```

Swift 2 :

```
   extension String  {
        var isNumber : Bool {
            get{
                return !self.isEmpty && self.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet) == nil
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: For Swift 3: `self.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil`

Comment: What's the point of adding .invertedSet instead of changing the return to != nil? Is it better runtime or something?

Comment: This did not handle negative numbers for me. But 'return Double(self) != nil' did.

Answer (score 47):

Be aware that checking a string/number using the `Int` initializer has limits. Specifically, a max value of 2^32-1 or 4294967295. This can lead to problems, as a phone number of 8005551234 will fail the `Int(8005551234)` check despite being a valid number.

A much safer approach is to use `NSCharacterSet` to check for any characters matching the decimal set in the range of the string.

```
let number = "8005551234"
let numberCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
if !number.isEmpty && number.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(numberCharacters) == nil {
    // string is a valid number
} else {
    // string contained non-digit characters
}
```

Additionally, it could be useful to add this to a `String` extension.

```
public extension String {

    func isNumber() -> Bool {
        let numberCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
        return !self.isEmpty && self.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(numberCharacters) == nil
    }

}
```

Comment: If the string is empty it will still return true.  po  "".rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)  nil

Comment: @CryingHippo try adding a `!number.isEmpty` check

Comment: What's the point of adding `.invertedSet` instead of changing the return to `!= nil`? Is it better runtime or something?

Comment: @TommyK if you check for non-inverted set, then you see if String contains numbers, but you don't know if it's digits only.

Comment: this is now `if !text_of_just_numbers.isEmpty && text_of_just_numbers.isEmpty.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil {
            //is numeric
        }` in Swift 4.2

Answer (score 31):

I think the nicest solution is:

```
extension String {
    var isNumeric : Bool {
        return Double(self) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: validates for double or int. nice!

Answer (score 21):

Starting from Swift 2, String.toInt() was removed. 
A new Int Initializer was being introduced: Int(str: String)

```
for target in ["abc", "94761178","790"]
{
  if let number = Int(target)
  {
     print("value: \(target) is a valid number. add one to get :\(number+1)!")
  }
  else
  {
    print("value: \(target) is not a valid  number.")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is inaccurate for numbers larger than 4294967295 (e.g. a ten digit phone number with an area > 429)

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3, 4

```
extension String {
    var isNumber: Bool {
        let characters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
        return !self.isEmpty && rangeOfCharacter(from: characters) == nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Simple solution like this:

```
extension String {
    public var isNumber: Bool {
        return !isEmpty && rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think using `NumberFormatter` is an easy way:
(**Swift 5**)

```swift
import Foundation

extension String {

    private static let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    var isNumeric : Bool {
        Self.numberFormatter.number(from: self) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Allocating `NumberFormatter` is an expensive operation, so it should be avoided.

Comment: @Krodak I changed it to use a shared formatter

Answer (score 4):

The correct way is to use the `toInt()` method of `String`, and an optional binding to determine whether the conversion succeeded or not. So your loop would look like:

```
let myArray = ["abc", "94761178","790"]

for val in myArray {
    if let intValue = val.toInt() {
        // It's an int
        println(intValue)
    } else {
        // It's not an int
        println(val)
    }
}
```

The `toInt()` method returns an `Int?`, so an optional `Int`, which is `nil` if the string cannot be converted ton an integer, or an `Int` value (wrapped in the optional) if the conversion succeeds.

The method documentation (shown using CMD+click on `toInt` in Xcode) says:

> If the string represents an integer that fits into an Int, returns the corresponding integer. This accepts strings that match the regular expression "[-+]?[0-9]+" only.

Answer (score 4):

This way works also with strings with mixed numbers:

```
public extension String {
func isNumber() -> Bool {
    return !self.isEmpty && self.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil && self.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters) == nil
}}
```

So u get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 version

```
func isNumber(stringToTest : String) -> Bool {
    let numberCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
    return !s.isEmpty && s.rangeOfCharacter(from:numberCharacters) == nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept a more fine-grained approach (i.e. accept a number like *4.5* or *3e10*), you proceed like this:

```
func isNumber(val: String) -> Bool
{
   var result: Bool = false
   let parseDotComNumberCharacterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
   parseDotComNumberCharacterSet.formUnionWithCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ".e"))

            let noNumberCharacters = parseDotComNumberCharacterSet.invertedSet
            if let v = val
            {
                result = !v.isEmpty && v.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(noNumberCharacters) == nil
            }
   return result
}
```

For even better resolution, you might draw on regular expression..

Comment: This will incorrectly return true for strings like `...........` and `e.e.e.e.e`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0**

We can also check :

```
 //MARK: - NUMERIC DIGITS
        class func isString10Digits(ten_digits: String) -> Bool{

            if !ten_digits.isEmpty {

                let numberCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
                return !ten_digits.isEmpty && ten_digits.rangeOfCharacter(from: numberCharacters) == nil 
            }
            return false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me for Swift 3/4

```
  func isNumber(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: textField.text!)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
  //        return true 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for integers of any length.

```
func getIntegerStrings(from givenStrings: [String]) -> [String]
{
    var integerStrings = [String]()
    for string in givenStrings
    {
        let isValidInteger = isInteger(givenString: string)
        if isValidInteger { integerStrings.append(string) }
    }
    return integerStrings
}

func isInteger(givenString: String) -> Bool
{
    var answer = true
    givenString.forEach { answer = ("0"..."9").contains($0) && answer }
    return answer
}

func getIntegers(from integerStrings: [String]) -> [Int]
{
    let integers = integerStrings.compactMap { Int($0) }
    return integers
}

let strings = ["abc", "94761178", "790", "18446744073709551615000000"]
let integerStrings = getIntegerStrings(from: strings)
let integers = getIntegers(from: integerStrings)

print(integerStrings) // ["94761178", "790", "18446744073709551615000000"]
print(integers) // [94761178, 790]
```

However, as pointed out by @Can, you can get the integer value for the number only up to 2^31 - 1 (signed integer limit on 32-bit arch). For the larger value, however, you will still get the string representation.

Answer (score 0):

This code will return an array of converted integers:

```swift
["abc", "94761178","790"].map(Int.init) // returns [ nil, 94761178, 790 ]
```

OR

```swift
["abc", "94761178","790"].map { Int($0) ?? 0 } // returns [ 0, 94761178, 790 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    extension String {
        var isNumber: Bool {
            return !isEmpty && rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
        }
    }
        
        let numericString = "12345"
        let nonNumericString = "abc123"
        
        print(numericString.isNumber)    // true
        print(nonNumericString.isNumber) // false
        
extension String {
 var isSignedNumber: Bool {
            let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-").union(CharacterSet.decimalDigits)
            return !isEmpty && rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacters.inverted) == nil
        }
}
    
        let positiveNumber = "+123"
        let negativeNumber = "-456"
        let nonNumericString = "abc123"
        
        print(positiveNumber.isSignedNumber) // true
        print(negativeNumber.isSignedNumber) // true
        print(nonNumericString.isSignedNumber) // false
```

Answer (score -6):

Get the following isInteger() function from the below stackoverflow post posted by corsiKa:
[Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)

And I think this is what you want to do (where nameOfArray is the array you want to pass)

```
void convertStrArrayToIntArray( int[] integerArray ) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nameOfArray.length(); i++) {
        if (!isInteger(nameOfArray[i])) {
            integerArray[i] = nameOfArray[i].toString();
        }
    }

}
```