# Do an integer check without using exceptions

Tags: java, event-handling, isnumeric

I have been working with Java for a very short time, so please be patient with me.  I'm working on a program for an INTRODUCTION to java class and I have to create a simple calculator (no GUI) without using exceptions, but that still captures input errors.  I was able to do the exception handler with no problem, but this one is driving me bonkers!! I need an alternative to the statement "if (a==char || b==char)" Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class calculator_No_Event {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int a,b,c;
    char d;
    boolean e;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    try
    {   
        System.out.print(" Enter the first number: ");
        a=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        b=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter + or - :");
        String f=input.next();
        d=f.charAt(0);


        if (a==char || b==char)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }   
        else
        {
            switch(d)
            {
                case '+':
                    c =a+b;
                    System.out.print(a + "+" + b + "=" + c);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    c =a-b;
                    System.out.print(a + "-" + b + "=" + c);
                    break;
            }
        }
}
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code does not even compile; make the prior effort to _at least_ make it compile. By undergoing this effort and reading the appropriate documentation, you'll learn a lot along the way.

Comment: well of course it doesn't compile, that's the problem.  My issue lies in the statement "if (a=char || b=char)"  this statement does not work.  the program compiles fine without the if statement.  What I'm looking for is an alternative to this statement.  Apologies if my issue was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You should call [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) before calling [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29). Likewise with [`Scanner.hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) and [`Scanner.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You are showing a lot of misunderstandings with this one line

```
if (a = char || b = char)
```

1. I assume you mean to use the [`equal to`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator, rather than the [`assignment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) operator `== instead of =`
2. `a` and `b` (*and `c`*) are `int`s, as declared in `main`. So we know they will never be `char`s, unless you convert them to chars - but then they would always be chars. `int` and `char` are different types, and the `1` character could be either type - so trying to do it as you are just won't work.
3. A google search for *check if string is number* returns [Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java), However, in this case [@ElliottFrisch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26849852/2974766) is the method you probably want to use. Learning to look at the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) whenever you use a new Java class (*like [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)*) is very valuable and can lead to a lot better understanding and knowledge of the classes you are using.

Comment: so if a user enters a letter instead of a number this will catch it?

Comment: I've linked to multiple solutions - I'm not sure which you are referring to. But yes, any of them could be a possible solution after you read about the methods and figure out how you would implement it.