# Converting a String from Byte array to int

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I've been googling all night for this problem since it is my first time to use arduino and android. My question is, how can I convert the variable `data` *String to int? I've been getting NumberFormatException whenever I do:
`int pulse = Integer.ParseInt(data);`

My objective here is to be able to get the data coming from the arduino and have it as an integer, for me to be able to compare it.

ADDITIONAL:
The variable "data" is a pulse rate. I need to have it converted to int so I can compare the value if the pulse rate is still normal or not.
After hours of searching I found out that what I am trying to convert to int is not purely a string since it came from the arduino, now my problem is how can I make the variable "data" an integer.

This is my code:

```
public void run()
        {                
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
            {
                try 
                {
                    final int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                final byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {   

                                        Intent i = new Intent(Bluetooth.this, Home.class);
                                        i.putExtra("theBPM",data);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well if you ran `parseInt` on the String and got that exception, then your `String` is not purely a number. So how can you expect to convert it to a numeric representation?

Comment: What is your string?

Comment: Problem is your input data, it is not a int representaiton,

Comment: @Kon Yeah. I know. But I dont have a clue on how to get it right.

Comment: @JClassic the "data" variable.

Comment: What is a sample value

Comment: @Rosselle You're not quite understanding, I think. You need to look at the content of your `data` variable. What is it? You should parse it accordingly. What does it contain exactly.

Comment: Okay let me update my question instead.

Comment: Can you paste code you executing on arduino to send data over BT?

Comment: @JJRoman the whole code? Or you just need the part that sends?

Comment: @Rosselle yup If you could post the method where you actually putting data to send buffer. Which library are you using for arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing/logging/making a toast to see what is in *data*. This can happen only when *data* has characters other than digits or may be you have a double(decimal) value in *data*. For that you might need to use *Double.parseDouble(data)*.

Comment: Woah. That was it! How'd you know that my variable might not be really an integer?

Comment: I tried all possible cases to generate NumberFormatException. Integer.parseInt(data) even works for negative integers :)
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that the problem is String to int and you already stepped in debug mode or make some Toast message that you are getting the string representation as expected.

You can try the following option:

- You can check if you have data for parsing
- Remove unnecessary white spaces (trim or String.split)
- Create a helper method to check for a String if it is a valid numeric
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5439547/3448799