# How to check a value of a variable is an integer in Selenium WD using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
for product_name in self.mydriverOne.product_container.product_name:
    rt=product_name.text[:-1]
    print rt
```

I need to validate the variable **rt** is an `integer value`. How can I do it in `selenium web driver` using Python?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use some python related coding for this. As you already have value in 'rt' which is probably is a string. 
Now you just have to check whether it contains numeric values. I mean whether string is like '1234'.
Refer this : [How do I check if a string is a number (float) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python)

Also,

[Checking whether a variable is an integer or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not)

Comment: are there any way to solve this using Assertions in selenium ?

Comment: I guess thing you are looking for is that variable "rt" has numeric values like "12345" etc. right?
I am not sure about python but in java this again can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java