# Check if a String is Integer

Tags: java

I need to check whether the String is an Integer. And I found such solution:

```
private boolean isInteger(String str) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a more beautiful and proper way to do this without try/catch clause?

Comment: have you considered regex?

Comment: the code you posted is very bad, since it "abuses" Exception Handling

Comment: I find this solution quite beautiful. And why oh earth should it "abuse" Exception Handling?

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion-based. There is no such thing as an objectively "more beautiful" code. Only right or wrong. And note that the two given answers are **wrong** (well, subtely wrong).

Comment: Do you call something like 1.0 an integer?

Comment: ... and this question is the n'th duplicate of [What's the best way to check to see if a String represents an integer in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java) (or even [Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)) or ...

Comment: @MarioA "And why oh earth should it "abuse" Exception Handling?" => Because exceptions should be used for _exceptional cases_ and not for normal _execution flow_ (Joshua Bloch, Effective Java, Item 57).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: As the exception is thrown by Integer.parseInt() I would consider it an exceptional case.

Comment: @MarioA Exactly! And the case that a string does _not_ represent an integer is a _normal_ execution flow for the question that this method shall answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try a regex like:

**Code**

```
private boolean isInteger(String str) {
    return str.matches("\\-?\\d+");
}
```

**Edit**

Thanks @Maloubobola for noting that my first attempt would not parse signed integers.

Comment: This introduces a subtle bug: a Long would match whereas the code in the OP's question would not.

Comment: Tunaki is right. Maybe add additional a Integer MIN/MAX check

Answer (score 3):

You can try regex. Here is one for positive and negative numbers

```
private boolean isInt(String string) {
    return string.matches("-?\\d+");
}
```

Comment: This introduces a subtle bug: a Long would match whereas the code in the OP's question would not.

Comment: Right. I did not think about it. Maybe check min/max value, or limit the number of digit. Max value for an integer is `2147483647` which contains 10 digits, so in some case (eg you are sure your integer is not 10 digits long) you can use `string.matches("-?\\d{1,9}");`.