# How to check whether the string is able to convert to float or int

Tags: java, android, parsing

I would like to check whether the string is able to convert to float or int.

For example:

I received

```
temp = 36.50
```

This value can be converted into float using

```
float Temp = Float.parseFloat(temp);
```

But what if I received

```
temp = 36.#0
```

My app will crash. So how can I check whether the string I received is able to convert to float?

Also for Int how do I do that?

Comment: Well, use a `try-catch` block. Or if you hate exceptions, try a regex to check whether input string is a valid float value

Comment: try parsing using both `parseInt` and `parseFloat` in a try-catch block with `parseFloat` first. Whenever you successfully parse one, store a boolean value. In the end, read the boolean value to check.

Comment: Also note that even `36.0` can fail to parse depending on the local language

Comment: Have a look at this question and it's accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
float temp = 0 ;
    try {
    temp = Float.parseFloat(temp);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // Not a float    
    }     
 /*
    you can do something with temp variables in here
 */
```

Comment: Throwing exception won't cause the app to stop right? Thank you.

Comment: @cashOveride thanks!!!

Comment: @crashOveride This is handy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if String is Integer or not then convert it to avoid crashes or try-catch.

Please check this link to learn how

[Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)