# Inject value into Jackson converter/deserializer

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, deserialization, dropwizard

I'm porting a legacy API to Java from a Ruby app that takes full advantage of not being statically typed.

In one such situation, the API accepts from the JSON body a `user_id` that is either a numeric  user ID or the string `"me"`, (which should be converted to the ID of the user making the request before being saved to the database). The method looks like this:

```java
@PUT
@Path("{key}")
@UnitOfWork
public Response getMyObjByKey(@PathParam("key") String key, MyObj myObj) {
    myObjDAO.save(myObj);
}
```

I have a converter that I want to look something like this:

```java
public class UserIdConverter extends StdConverter<String, Integer> {

    @Inject
    @AuthUser
    protected AuthenticatedUser user;

    public Integer convert(String strUserId) {
        // if strUserId is "me"
        return user.getId();
    }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work because of...something to do with the lifecycle that causes `user` to be `null`.

My question is: Is there a way for me to access the user object in the converter?

Comment: Can you not access the user with `@Auth user` in the `PUT` method and send it to the converter?

Comment: It is accessible in the resource class, yes. I'm not sure how I would send it to the converter though since I'm not explicitly calling `convert` and I believe the deserialization happens before the first statement in the PUT method

Comment: Okay it seems I am a bit confused then. When is the `UserIdConverter` present in the transaction? Is it part of `MyObj`?

Comment: It's just an implementation of Jackson's `StdConverter`. The model is annotated with `@JacksonDeserialize(converter = UserIdConverter.class)` and Jackson does whatever it does with that.

Comment: I see. I will suggest moving the conversion itself to the resource method as I don't see a way to get the authenticated user during the deserialization process. i.e. convert the number if necessary, then save to the DB. You can the get the user with `@Auth`.

Comment: Right, my problem is that deserialization happens before the method is even entered. That is, since the POJO stores `user_id` as an int, an exception is thrown since it can't save the string `"me"` to `MyObj`. Therefore I cannot convert it within the resource method. I suppose I can just change the model to accept a string and then convert the string to an int before saving to the DB but that adds a bunch of conversions around the app that I'd prefer not to do.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge its not possible to access the `User` during the deserialization. Try a custom deserializer and place an indicating `int` as the id if the `String` "me" is received. Something like:

```
public class MyObjDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyObj>{

    @Override
    public MyObj deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);

        MyObj myobj = new MyObj();
        myobj.setName(node.get("name").textValue());
        // set other attributes...

        String idString = node.get("id").textValue();
        int id = -1;
        if(!idString.equals("me")) { 
           // another option: use idString.matches("-?\\d+") to check if its a number - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801999/7015661
            id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
        }

        myobj.setId(id);

        return myobj;
    }

}
```

Then in your `MyObj` class place `@JsonDeserialize(using = MyObjDeserializer.class)` to use your own deserializer.

Now if the id is "-1", you can get the user's own id in the resource method as follows:

```
@PUT
@Path("{key}")
@UnitOfWork
public Response getMyObjByKey(@PathParam("key") String key, MyObj myObj, @Auth Optional<User> user) {

    if(myObj.getId() == -1){
        if(!user.isPresent) // something went very wrong
             throw new RuntimeException("User not authenticated");

       myObj.setId(user.get().getId()); // set the id to its correct value
    }

    myObjDAO.save(myObj);
}
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is actually what I'm currently doing but was hoping there was a cleaner way (since many endpoints use `MyObj`, and forgetting to copy the -1 check to any one of them could result in invalid values being saved to the DB). I think I'll keep this question open for a bit to make sure nobody has a better solution.

Comment: My pleasure. Your right, copying the check is quite tedious. Hopefully someone has a more elegant solution. I'll keep an eye on the question as I'm curious to see how such a solution can be implemented.

Comment: Looks like a `!` is missing into `if(idString.equals("me"))`

Comment: Well spotted! I fixed it. Thanks.