# How can I validation main method

Tags: java

How to validate this method specially

```
    System.out.println("Enter number of vertices");
    n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

this. please help me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter number of vertices");
    n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    graph2 g = new graph2(n);
    g.createGraph();

    System.out.println("\nEnter the source node:");
    int s = g.getNumber();
    System.out.println("\nEnter the target node:");
    int t = g.getNumber();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      algomain2 ff = new  algomain2(g,s,t);

    System.out.println("\nFinal Residual Network with no augmenting path");

    System.out.print("\nCapacity Flow matrix for your graph is :\n");
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        System.out.print("     "+ff.f[i][j]+"/"+g.cf[i][j]);
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    int maxflow=0;
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("\n Max flow is: ");
    for(int i=1; i<=n;i++)
        if(g.adj[s][i]==1)
            maxflow=maxflow + ff.f[s][i];

    System.out.println(maxflow);
    System.out.println("Time taken (ms):"+ (end-start));

}
```

Comment: Could you please tell in detail like what you actually want to get?

Comment: @S.MANDAL I want to put only numbers without any characters

Comment: @qwertyuio does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine);`, `Integer.parseInt()` always tries to convert your input to the integer one, and assign to integer variable. You don't have to worry about it, as `Integer.parseInt()` method internally does this.

And as you throw `NumberFormatException` in method signature, if `Integer.parseInt()` does not get integer value or something that it can't convert to integer, the `NumberFormatException` exception will be thrown.

So, if you give number input, `n` will store the input and you program runs well. If you give input except number (means something that contains character), code will give exception and terminate the execution.

To handle it, you can put your code inside `try-catch` block to make it properly handle. Like below

```
try{

    System.out.println("Enter number of vertices");
    n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){

    System.out.println("Please enter number only");
}
```

Or you can make some method to check whether the input is integer or not. If it is integer, return `Integer.parseInt(param)`, else return `false`. And inside this method, just put your code (basically the above code snippet will be there with proper return statement)