# Check if String array of digits contains symbol

Tags: java, arrays, string

Got `String[][] arr` which contains only `digit` in `String` format.

```
 if (array[i][j].equals("[a-zA-Z]+")){ - not help
```

How to check if this `arr` contains `symbol`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mystring.matches("\\d+");
```

Returns true when all the chars are digits. This won't break even if the number is greater than the limit of `int`.

You can see some other examples here

[Determine if a String is an Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

You can check each cell in the array for its ascii value.

for exampe:
if its between 65-90 its a capital letter

http://www.asciitable.com/