# Validate a String to see if it is an Integer?

Tags: java

Not keen on using the `parseInteger` solution, it is ugly, and as Joshua Bloch says you should "Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions". Of course, I can use something like block of code below, but it doesn't guarantee it is an Integer.

```
for (char c : str.toCharArray())
{
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: _but it doesn't guarantee it is an Integer_ Can you explain, why? If a string is digit-only it should be

Comment: A bad input _IS_ an exceptional condition, I think

Comment: `Integer`, as in 32-bit integer, or an integer, as in arbitrarily integer that can be represented with `BigInteger`?

Comment: You can rewrite the `parseInt()` method to return `false` instead of throwing an exception. The method is pretty easy to read. Would that be a better solution to you?

Comment: What you are suggesting is more or less what `parseInteger` does. Just look at the source code and adapt it.

Comment: There may be some tips [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/237159/1005481).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions" is a good practice to follow in general, but it's not a hard-and-fast rule.  I think that this is one of the cases where using exceptions is better than the alternatives.

Since `parseInteger()` can return any possible `int` value, you can't use any other return value to indicate failure.  If you know you're never going to process a particular value (such as `-1` or `-2147483648`), you can return that as a sentinel value to indicate a parse failure.

The only alternative is to return a `boolean` indicating success or failure and to store the parsed value into a parameter.  However, since function calls are always pass-by-value in Java, you'd need to create a new class to do this:

```
public class IntWrapper
{
    int value;
}
...

public static boolean myParseInt(String s, IntWrapper outValue)
{
    try
    {
        outValue.value = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
...

IntWrapper value = new IntWrapper();
if (myParseInt(value))
{
    // Use value.value
}
else
{
    // Parsing failed
}
```

Given these alternatives, I think the simplest usage is just to use exceptions and deal with them appropriately, even though non-numeric input may not necessary be an "exceptional" condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave it with exception but if you REALLY want solution without exception you can copy method parseInt() from [this](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java/?v=source) site with java internal classes and change it a little bit

(You can modify it a little bit more, since you do not need result)

```
public static false isValidInt(String s, int radix)
                throws NumberFormatException
    {
        if (s == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX) {
            return false;
        }

        if (radix > Character.MAX_RADIX) {
            return false;
        }

        int result = 0;
        boolean negative = false;
        int i = 0, len = s.length();
        int limit = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int multmin;
        int digit;

        if (len > 0) {
            char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
            if (firstChar < '0') { // Possible leading "-"
                if (firstChar == '-') {
                    negative = true;
                    limit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                } else
                    return false;

                if (len == 1) // Cannot have lone "-"
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            multmin = limit / radix;
            while (i < len) {
                // Accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE
                digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
                if (digit < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (result < multmin) {
                    return false;
                }
                result *= radix;
                if (result < limit + digit) {
                    return false;
                }
                result -= digit;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
public static boolean isInteger(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int length = str.length();
    if (length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
int i = 0;
if (str.charAt(0) == '-') {
    if (length == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    i = 1;
}
for (; i < length; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c <= '/' || c >= ':') {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Already answered here: [What's the best way to check to see if a String represents an integer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java)