# How to check if a text contains only int values in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I want to determine if `JTextField.getText()` contains only numbers between 0-9, where anything else is not accepted such as letters and other characters. What's a good way to do this? thanks.

Comment: With `JTextField.getText().matches("\\d+");`

Comment: Parse it and catch the possible exception. Shouldn't be too expensive considering it requires user input (and thus won't be likely to be done thousands of times in a row).

Comment: Or just use `StringUtils.isNumeric()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to check to see if a String represents an integer in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java)

Comment: int value(S), plural? so "123 456 789" would be ok? e.g. ints separated by spaces?

Comment: @MarcB he did say "other characters" for unacceptable characters, so I'd assume space is out.

Comment: @pennstatephil: yeah,but also  says valueS, implying there may be more than one.

Comment: @MarcB, ah, I read that as more than one character, that is "123" contains only int values. could be a typo, too.

Comment: yeah, could go either way. multiple individual "int" values, e.g "123", being "three ints", but one single value

Comment: Use a `JSpinner` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NetBeans to build your GUI, you just need to put regular JTextFields in your GUI and in the creation code, you will specify the constructor of IntegerField.

> OR

Use JFormattedTextField capabilities.

`numberField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance());`.

Have a look at example(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).