# String Exception in Java

Tags: java

I want to know if a particular exception is available for catching non-`String` input in java.

My purpose is that if a user enters other than `String` input, it goes to a catch block and displays "Enter String input".

I know that for numeric input there is `NumberFormatException`, so is there any Exception like this?

Comment: What kind of input isn't a string?

Comment: sorry what i meant was if input contains numeric data, i know numeric data is also consider as String, So any solution?

Comment: @user3666220 Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java) out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A numeric input can always be interpreted as a String, so there is no such exception.

You'll have to check the characters of the String to find out if it contains digits.