# Best way to check if a value is an integer?

Tags: java

There are several ways to decide if a value is an integer or not. 
All of the ways i know are using the divide operation.

Which method is the fastest and:
Is there a method to do this without doing floating point operations?

EDIT: For clarification, my program is only dealing with integer and double values. Here is some of my code:

```
 for (int i = 6;; i++) {

        for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            double number1 = i;
            double number2 = j;
            double d = number1 / number2;
            int help = (int)d;
            if( (d - help) == 0.0){
                System.out.println("Whole number found");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your input? Text?

Comment: No, only numbers. Mostly int / int

Comment: What is 'int / int'? Show us some Java code so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Did you read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java)?

Comment: Could you please show one of the ways you know and wish to avoid as an illustration?

Comment: 5 / 3 , 16 / 3 ,  28 / 15 ...

Comment: @user1438038 We are still not sure if the input is a String.

Comment: @OfficerBacon Please describe in more detail what you are trying to do. As it is now, your question will be closed because it is unclear what you ask.

Comment: Is is possible that what you actually want to do is checking whether an integer `a` is divisible by another integer `b`?  If so, `b * (a / b) == a` would do the trick without floating point arithmetic or string representations.

Comment: If this question was about JavaScript, I would understand. This way it seems completely misguided. *The static type system* will tell you if a "value" is an integer. The program will *refuse to compile* if you try to pass a non-integer to a method expecting an integer. And if that doesn't give you the answer you expect, then fix your question to something with more substance.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `int / int` will also be an `int` due to the rules of integral division. You need to promote one of them to floating point or use the idiom `1.0 * a / b` if you want to retain a remainder.

If you have a floating point number, `f`, then

`java.lang.Math.floor(f) - f == 0` is probably the best way.

It avoids an intermediate cast to `int` which can overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want!

```
    String str = "1";
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Not a number");
    }
```

Comment: Clearer than my answer (so plus one in that respect), but order of magnitudes slower.

Comment: What if `str = "12 / 7"`? That's what is written in the commetns above.

Comment: @LutzHorn: I feel that is beyond the scope. We're not trying to build an expression parser here.

Comment: Well, that's why I've voted to close this question because it is not clear.