# How expensive is String to Int to String conversion in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I am attempting to check whether a particular string is an `Int` (or `Boolean` or `Long` so on and so forth) but **don't really need** it to be parsed it to an `Int` (or others). I can think of two options. First, to do a `var.toInt.toString` or just return the actual string on which `toInt` was invoked if it's an `Int`. While both work just fine, I wanted to know if the former is a lot more expnsive compared to the latter. FYI, I won't be parsing really long strings this way, but I will be going through terabytes of data.

Comment: You should write a benchmark with ScalaMeter and find out: http://scalameter.github.io/

Comment: `toInt` et al throw exceptions when they fail, so I think it's safe to guess that they're more costly than, e.g. a precompiled regular expression.

Comment: What do you mean by "is an Int"? Has only digits and optional leading -? Is in the range of an Integer? Similarly for Long, with the added fun point that every Int could be a Long too.

Comment: I would be wary about doing a regex - it's going to be very easy to mess up and miss an edge case that the existing parsing libraries cover, especially with something like what @TheArchetypalPaul points out where any `Int` value is also an acceptable `Long`.  It may save you a few cycles, but you'll regret it when it produces incorrect results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, to answer the exact question:

`.toString` takes a few tens of ns on my machines, with the details depending of course on the machine and also on how long the string representation of the int is (~2x difference between the shortest and longest).  `.toInt` takes less (about 1/2 to 3/4 of the time of `toString`).

Does this matter?  Well, over terabytes of data (mostly numeric, I'm guessing) you'll have trillions of tens of nanoseconds, or tens of thousands of seconds.  So maybe it does; it'll be hours of extra compute time.

But that's not what's going to be happening.  If you use `toInt` on something that is *not* an integer, you're going to throw an exception.  Exceptions are really slow--usually at least a couple of microseconds.  If more than about 1/1000 of your supposed ints are not actually ints, you'll be spending a huge fraction of your time creating big stack traces for your parsing exceptions and then throwing them away.

You can try to use a regex.  That's generally about 10x more expensive than just doing the parse, but 10x cheaper than throwing the exception.  Still not a good choice unless you have several extra compute days to throw at the problem, especially since the regex will only tell you if it's int-*like*, not if it's in range, so you have to parse it anyway (and catch exceptions or do fiddly bounds checking).

So if you really want it to be fast, you end up having to do the validation manually, indexing through the string, grabbing characters with `charAt`, and so on.  Yes, it's a pain.  But if you parse it yourself, it'll be about as fast as a single `.toInt`.  It's a big ugly block of code.  Using `java.lang.Character.digit` is generally the way to go if people might have number values in other character sets (you can catch the -1 return and bail).  Don't forget to handle positive and negative slightly differently (due to the different range).

Addendum: you might think `java.util.Scanner` is just the ticket.  It steps through data and has a `hasNextInt` method.  Unfortunately, it's dreadfully slow.

See also [What's the best way to check to see if a String represents an integer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159) for Java answers to the question (none of which are idea IMO).

Comment: Fifteen words into your answer I thought, "Oh, this must be Rex", and I was right :-)