# Comparing String to int JAVA

Tags: java, string, compare, comparison, jgrasp

I am trying to figure out how to make sure a String variable does not have a number as a string. I cannot Import anything.

I have tried

```
NameArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("")) || Integer.parseInt(NameArray[i]) >= 48 && Integer.parseInt(NameArray[i]) < 58
```

but it did not work.

Comment: `"48".equals(NameArray[i].trim())` or some such, this way you avoid the issues of parsing a `String` which is not a number

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java

Comment: @Evelyn, as per my understanding you need to check if the string has any numeric value in it. Kindly check my answer and let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting string to number using Integer.parseInt(string).
If it gives an Exception than it is not a number.

```
public boolean validNumber(String number) 
{
   try 
   {
     Integer.parseInt(number);
   } 
   catch (NumberFormatException e) 
   {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8+, you might use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to generate a range (`[48, 58]`) and then check if that as a `String` is equal to your `NameArray`. Something like,

```
if (IntStream.rangeClosed(48, 58).anyMatch(x -> String.valueOf(x)
        .equals(NameArray[i]))) {

}
```

You mention that you want to make sure it doesn't contain a value - so perhaps you really want `noneMatch` like

```
if (IntStream.rangeClosed(48, 58).noneMatch(x -> String.valueOf(x)
        .equals(NameArray[i]))) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to check for a string which doesn't contain any numbers.
Try using regex `.*[0-9].*` which will check for occurrence of any numerical character in your string.

```
    String regex = ".*[0-9].*";

    // Returns true
    System.out.println("1".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("100".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("Stack 12 Overflow".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("aa123bb".matches(regex));

    // Returns false
    System.out.println("Regex".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("Java".matches(regex));
```