# How to skip an argument if it is of a certain type

Tags: java

So I am trying to figure out how to skip an argument if it contains a certain type for instance:

args: Blue 3 Red 7 Green 5 Yellow 2

I am wanting to store the numbers in an array and the colors in a separate array. So if args[i] is a string then store it in the color array and if it is an int store it in the numbers array. Something like if(args[i] == String) then so on and so forth. Obviously that doesn't work though so I was looking for another solution.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] colors = new String[] {};
        int[] number = new int[] {};
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            // stuck
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You may be looking for `instanceof` -- but since `args` is a `String[]`, _all_ of its elements will be String (or null). `instanceof` is often (but not always) a clue that you haven't gotten your abstractions quite right; you may be able to define an interface with a do-a-thing method, and several implementations of that (do-a-thing with a String, do-a-thing with an int, etc).

Comment: All args are Strings, try converting them

Comment: In order to determine whether a `String` contains digits only, use [static] method `parseInt(String)` of class `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: i think this question would help you,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java

Comment: wouldn't some rules on argument input help? e.g. mandate it to input as `Blue:3 Red:7 Green:5 Yellow:2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            try {
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                colors.add(args[i]);
            }
        }

        String[] colorsArray = colors.toArray(new String[0]);
        int[] number = numbers.stream().mapToInt(num -> num).toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. Buy the way, `new String[size]` does not give performans with `new String[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] colors = new String[args.length] ;
        int color_ix=0;
        int number_idx=0;
        Integer[] number = new Integer[args.length] ;
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            if(args[i]==null) {continue;}
            try
            {
               number[number_idx]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
               number_idx++;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
              colors[color_ix]=args[i];
              color_ix++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-----Number-----");
        for(int i=0;i<number_idx;i++)
        {
          System.out.println(number[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("-----Colors-----");
        for(int i=0;i<color_ix;i++)
        {
          System.out.println(colors[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

ouput
$ java Main Blue Green 3 Red 2 Black 1

```
-----Number-----
3
2
1
-----Colors-----
Blue
Green
Red
Black
```

Comment: `if(args[i]==null) {continue;}` - how is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply

**1.** create `ArrayList` for numbers and strings

**2.** Add values to lists according to *regex* match which checks if the argument is number or string

**3.** convert `ArrayList` to `arrays`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (Pattern.matches("-?\\d+", args[i])) {
            numberList.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
        } else {
            strList.add(args[i]);
        }
    }
    String[] colors  = strList.toArray(new String[0]);
    int[] number = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(numberList.toArray(new Integer[numberList.size()]));
}
```

Comment: For better performance, we should compile the `Pattern` outside of the for loop and re-use it for different strings. Internally, `Pattern.matches(..` does this -> `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()`.

Comment: @DarshanMehta:  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // args = Blue 3 Red 7 Green 5 Yellow 2
    String[] colors = Arrays.stream(args).filter(str -> str.matches("\\D+")).toArray(String[]::new);
    int[] number = Arrays.stream(args).filter(str -> str.matches("[-+]?\\d+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(colors));    // [Blue, Red, Green, Yellow]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));    // [3, 7, 5, 2]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Commons Lang [StringUtils.isNumeric](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-) to check if it is number.

```
//initialized with max length
String[] colors = new String[args.length];
int[] number = new int[args.length];
int colorIndex=-1;
int numberIndex=-1;
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
{
    //if number add to number array else to colors
    if(StringUtils.isNumeric(args[i])){
        number[++numberIndex]=Integer.valueOf(args[i]);
    }else{
        colors[++colorIndex]=args[i];
    }
}
```