# Alertbox not showing on button click

Tags: java, android

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Add new product");
        builder.setView(subView);
        builder.create();

        builder.setPositiveButton("ADD PRODUCT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final String name = nameField.getText().toString();
                final int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText().toString());


                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || quantity <= 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong. Check your input values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Product newProduct = new Product(name, quantity);
                    mDatabase.addProduct(newProduct);

                    //refresh the activity
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }

            }
        });
```

This is my code where the product is the database and there are two fields in it: `name` and `quantity`. Now when I leave the fields empty the application crashes.

I have even tried like:

```
if(nameFields.getText().tostring().isEmpty() ||quantityFields.getText.toString.isEmpty())
{
//Toast for error
}
```

If I enter a single field in the alert builder, i.e. when I enter only the `name` it accepts the value which it should not. Instead, it must pop an alert for not entering all required values. How can I set up this alert?

This is the error I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.inducesmile.androidsqliteexample, PID: 15729
                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                      at com.inducesmile.androidsqliteexample.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Please post your error and subView.xml file code Or you can check like this for the field is empty or not
name.matches("")

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.inducesmile.androidsqliteexample, PID: 13147
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)

Comment: The problem is in the following line `final int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText().toString());`. You're trying to convert an empty string `""` to an integer. Which naturally will raise an exception. You need to check if your String is a correct integer.  Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java fore more details about converting string to integer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
final int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText().toString());
```

You are doing this no matter what, even if `quantityField` is empty. You only check if it is empty *after* attempting to parse it to an Integer. The error is telling you that.

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

So perhaps rewrite your `onClick` function to be the following:

```
final String name = nameField.getText().toString();
final String quantityStr = quantityField.getText().toString();

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(quantityStr))
{
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong. Check your input values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
    final int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityStr);
    // TODO: here you can check if quantity <= 0 and handle that appropriately
    Product newProduct = new Product(name, quantity);
    mDatabase.addProduct(newProduct);

    //refresh the activity
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

What I changed:

- first created a string `quantityStr`
- show an error if it's empty, just like you did for the `name` field
- parse it *after* it is confirmed to not be empty

Answer (score 0):

please add this line to bottom of codes

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```