# I have an int filled out by the user on the console and I need to check if the input given was a non number. How to I do that?

Tags: java, types, type-conversion, verification, typechecking

Java. In brackets you see what I want to do.

```
if (variableThatIsAnInt != [intType])
System.out.println("invalid option");
```

Comment: Please add the programming language tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

A variable which is an `int` or `Integer` can never be anything else than this type. This is only possible if you ditch the typing completely and define everything as an `Object` only.

As an example:

```
Integer myVar = 1;
Object myDirtyVar = myVar;
```

A check whether myVar is an instance of Integer would always be true.

What you are actually looking for is to check whether a String value is assignable to a numerical (in this case: Integer) number.

This can be done multiple ways, one way would be the following:

[What's the best way to check if a String represents an integer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/)

Another way is to try to parse/convert it and then catch the Exception ([NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)) which may appear if the `String` is not representing an `Integer`.