# how do i Check if the Entered Value is a Integer? and if it is, Then only rest of the Code gets Executed

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the Number you want the Maximum times the Pattern to Print while Increasing 1 each Time :");

    boolean isInteger = true;
    do {
      Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
      int a = Obj.nextInt();

      // The Condition I want is to check if INPUT 'a' has a integer value and execute rest of the code on the condition.
      if (a.hasNextInt()) {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
          int j;
          for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.println("a");
          }
          System.out.println();
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("Please Enter a Integer Value : ");
        isInteger = false;
      }
    } while (isInteger == false);
  }
}
```

Expected output of the above code:

```
*
**
***
****
```

Type of Pattern Several Number of times, then I thought doing this by taking user input. If the User input is an Integer then only rest of the code gets executed, else it should print `"Please Enter a Integer Value : "` and asks the user to enter another input. I'm new to Java.

How do I check if the entered value is an Integer?

Comment: Do you want to know if `a` is an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Use next() instead of nextInt() and check to see if the value is a string or a number to avoid errors by default.
Try like this

```
        System.out.println("Enter the Number you want the Maximum times the Pattern to Print while Increasing 1 each Time :\n");
        boolean isInteger = true;
        do {
            Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userInput = Obj.next();
            int number = 0;
            try {
                number = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
                isInteger = true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                isInteger = false;
            }
            if(isInteger) {
                int i, j;
                for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please Enter a Integer Value - " + userInput);
            }
        } while (isInteger == false);
```

Comment: Your catch clause is catching all exceptions, not just `NumberFormatException`, which will mask other errors in the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

> *"how do i Check if the Entered Value is a Integer? and if it is, Then only rest of the Code gets Executed ..."*

The typical recommendation is to use the *[Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))* method.
This method will throw *[NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)* for non-numeric values, so you can utilize a *[try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)* block.

```java
Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = Obj.next();
try {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(a);
} catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        
}
```

Here is a relevant *StackOverflow* question and answer regarding this approach.
*[StackOverflow – What's the best way to check if a String represents an integer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java)*.

If you are checking only integers, you can use the *[String#chars](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars())* method on *a*.
The *[Character#isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))* method will return *true* for `'0'` though `'9'`.

```java
isInteger = a.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
```

Or, you can also use the *[String#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))* method.
This uses a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*, as a *String* parameter.

```java
if (a.matches("\\d+"))
```

> *"... it should print `"Please Enter a Integer Value : "` and asks the user to enter another input. ..."*

In this case, start *isInteger* as *false*, and set it to *true* from the other *if block*.

> *"... Expected output of the above code:*
>
> ```
> *
> **
> ***
> ****
> ```

You're going to want to use *[print](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char))*, instead of *[println](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String))*.

```java
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    System.out.print('*');
}
System.out.println();
```

Here is the full code,

```java
System.out.println("Enter the Number you want the Maximum times the Pattern to Print while Increasing 1 each Time :");

boolean isInteger = false;
do {
    Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = Obj.next();

    // The Condition I want is to check if INPUT 'a' has a integer value and execute rest of the code on the condition.
    if (a.matches("\\d+")) {
        int i, length = Integer.parseInt(a);
        for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
            int j;
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print('*');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        isInteger = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please Enter a Integer Value : ");
    }
} while (isInteger == false);
```

Output

```
Enter the Number you want the Maximum times the Pattern to Print while Increasing 1 each Time :
4
*
**
***
****
```

Here is how I would write the same code.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String string;
int value, count;
boolean exit = false;
while (!exit) {
    string = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!string.matches("\\d+"))
        System.out.printf("invalid entry '%s'%n", string);
    else {
        value = Integer.parseInt(string);
        for (count = 1; count <= value; count++)
            System.out.println("*".repeat(count));
        exit = true;
    }
}
```